# Referencing an Express app from my router module

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I read from various posts here that a good way to structure an Express app is to create a routes.js module with contents such as:

```
exports.homepage = function (req, res) {
    // do something
}
```

Then, from my app.js:

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
app.get('/', routes.homepage);
```

This works a treat until I want to change my "do something" to do another request like so:

```
exports.homepage = function (req, res) {
    app.get('/sign-in', myCallbackFunc);
}
```

My routes.js knows nothing about app. How do I pass in/reference "app". Or is the way I've structured this incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, correctness can depend on your intent. So, why do you need to add the route `/sign-in` only *after* requesting `/`? Or, is that not what you were going for?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski It's for forwarding the user to the sign-in page if they aren't signed-in already.

Comment: Ah. Try [`res.redirect('/sign-in')`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) for that.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I can't pass a callback with that though can I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, how your project is structured.  But this, is how I would create the routes.js file:

```
var routes = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       // do something
    });

    app.get('/sign-in', function(req, res) {
       // do something
    });
};

module.exports = routes;
```

And the from your app.js, simply require your routes file like so:

```
require('./routes')(app);
```